# Stripe 503 error - illegal IP 127.0.0.1 webhook problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm working on setting up a webhook from Stripe. Essentially because it's a subscription model and I need to know if I shall keep on renewing the month or not. I'd like to do that through the event 'invoice.payment_succeeded'.

When I test my webhook url in stripe I get this:

```
host localhost:3000 resolves to illegal IP 127.0.0.1
```

my full endpoint is:

```
localhost:3000/hooks/receiver
```

route:

```
get 'hooks/receiver' => "hooks#receiver"
```

and the hooks controller looks like this:

```
class HooksController < ApplicationController
 require 'json'
 Stripe.api_key

 def receiver
  data_json = JSON.parse request.body.read

  p data_json['data']['object']['customer']

  if data_json[:type] == 'invoice.payment_succeded'
   make_active(data_event)
  end 

  if data_json[:type] == 'invoice.payment_failed'
   # something make_inactive(data_event)
  end
end

def make_active(data_event)
 @user = User.find_by_customer_token(data['data']['object']['customer'])
 @status = @user.statuses.pluck(:list_id).presence || -1
 Resque.enqueue(ScheduleTweets, @user.token, @user.id, @status)
end

 def make_inactive(data_event)

 end 
end
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use 127.0.0.1 or localhost as a webhook in Stripe. A webhook involves Stripe sending data from their serves to yours, but your 127.0.0.1 isn't available to Stripe since only you can access localhost.

Answer (score 8):

You could use something like ngrok to open your localhost to the interwebs
https://ngrok.com/